# I can't open phpMyAdmin, get error 301 or 500

Tags: centos, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I've installed phpMyAdmin, but I can't open it on any browser: [I get a 301 redirect](http://pastebin.com/c1r3AvZT)(*) if I browse to `http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin`. If I add a `/` to the end of the addres, **I get a 500 error status instead**.

<sup>(*) captured using Wireshark. If I use netcat from the terminal on the same host, I get [a 301  redirect to a ***different*** address](http://paste2.org/p/3075917).</sup>

The environment is a VM I've built for development/testing purposes, where I installed a [LEMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) (Linux / Nginx / MySQL / PHP) environment. It's a clean install of [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6 64bit running as guest on a Ubuntu 12.04 64bit host.  The VM is running in NATed mode with port forwarding. I can open `http://localhost:8080` on the guest machine and see the nginx welcome page. I can open a [phpinfo page](http://pastebin.com/9xfvfgUB) as well, so I know PHP is running.

I have installed the nginx, MySQM, PHP and phpMyAdmin packages each separately. I'm using the default settings for phpMyAdmin. After installig MySQL, I have ran the `mysql_secure_installation` command and, among other options, I disabled remote root access.

Here are my configuration files:

- `/etc/php.ini`: [link](http://pastebin.com/Z7GJamZv)
- `/etc/php.d/mysql.ini`: [link](http://pastebin.com/iiyYQrca)
- `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`: [link](http://pastebin.com/swwuYE3P)
- `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`: [link](http://pastebin.com/tgLvtRe2) (In order to run PHP scripts, I have customized it, following online tutorials, and *I'm not really sure of what I was doing*.)
- `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`: [link](http://pastebin.com/sGQ2dgis)

Comment: This question got 4 votes-to-close. Why? http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6455/why-is-my-question-being-vtced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were multiple causes preventing me from logging in to phpMyAdmin:

### mbstring

The error 500 generates a message `PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in /usr/share/php/gettext/gettext.inc on line 177` on the file `/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`. According to a comment on http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php I tried to install the `php-mbstring` package but it was already present.

Restarting the `php-fpm service` solved the error 500.

### php sessions

After solving the previous error, I got the following error:

[image]

`/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` had the line

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

but PHP's `session.save_path` variable is set to the inexistent `/var/lib/php/session` folder.

Creating a folder with proper permissions solved this error, I can login properly.

## trailing slash redirection

If I try to acess ***any*** address on this server without a trailing slash in the end of the URL, nginx is adding a trailing slash *and* removing its `:8080` part.  It doesn't happen if I leave the trailing slash.

(eg.: `http://localhost:8080/example` gets redirected to `http://localhost/example/`. The fact I have phpMyAdmin running *both* in the VM and on the host machine added more confusion as I would see the phpMyAdmin login dialog, but on the wrong destination).

It seems to be [a common nginx error](http://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+slash). I have googled and tried various solutions with no success. If I find a solution for my case I will update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Root logins must be allowed on the `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` configuration file.

Add the following line:

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = TRUE;

Comment: hello and welcome to SuperUser. please take some time explaining the syntax and details about what those command lines will perform. it may be relevant for future readers or to the QA himself.

Comment: I can't even see the phpmyadmin login screen. I've added the line to the cfg file, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html states the default value is `true`. I haven't set it to false, and it's not present on the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/var/log/nginx/error.log` to see what the error 500 says.

It looks like you're running two configurations (one on port 80 and another on 8080) which may conflict.

Comment: I'm not running two webserver configurations on the same machine. 8080 is a NAT redirect port for the guest VM, and 80 is the port for the host OS. Technically, they are on the same machine, but virtualized from each other.

Comment: Your suggestion for looking for log files, however, has put me in the right direction.